# Is there a class feature that improves effective Caster Level of used magic items?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, class-feature, caster-level

Many wondrous items and other equipment duplicate spell effects, typically at the Caster Level the item itself. I would be interested in making a character that used their own HD/Class Level/Caster Level in place of such magic items.

One example:

[Mask of the Skull](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/mask-of-the-skull/), 1/day CL 13 effect of [Finger of Death](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/finger-of-death). I think a really cool build would allow me to use this (and other 1-3 use per day magic items) at my current character level, so that at 15th level, Mask of the Skull would do 150 damage or save for 3d6+15.

Ideally, this would be a non-caster type because otherwise I'd just as likely make a Wizard with [Staff-Like Wand](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-discoveries/arcane-discoveries-paizo/staff-like-wand/). I'm not looking for tons of magical spellcasting, but to actually benefit more than just minimum CL items (without dealing with getting a GM to allow me to pay more for higher CL Wondrous Items).

Paizo material preferred, 3pp content allowed, no 3.5.

Comment: Are you restricted to *Pathfinder* material, or can *3.5* material be ported over?

Comment: Edited, no 3.5 but I'd be interested if there's a 3pp solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The [Arcane Savant](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/a-b/arcane-savant) can do this.

The Arcane Savant is a prestige class that focuses on getting the most from magic items.

At 3rd level, they can use their caster level on spells they cast using scrolls and wands.

> Scroll Master (Su)
>
> At 3rd level, an arcane savant can use his own caster level instead of the item’s caster level when using a scroll or other spell-completion item.

Since the Arcane Savant prestige class requires 5 hit dice as part of its prerequisites, the *earliest* a character can gain the Scroll Master ability is at 8 hit dice.  This is faster than the [Magician](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo-bard-archetypes/magician/) bard archetype, who gains a similar benefit at 10 (or more) hit dice.

At 10th level, the Arcane Savant gains their capstone ability, and can use their caster level for any single magic item.

> Item Master (Su)
>
> At 10th level, an arcane savant can spend an hour focusing his energies on a single non-charged magic item that requires an action to activate. At the end of this hour, that item becomes attuned to the arcane savant, and from that point on, that specific item can use the arcane savant’s caster level to resolve its effects rather than the item’s caster level. An arcane savant can change which item is attuned to him by repeating the attunement ritual, but he loses attunement to the previous item. An arcane savant can have only one item attuned to him at a time.

Note that the Arcane Savant is behind one caster level, although you can use the [Magical Knack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-knack/) trait to compensate. So if you multiclass Wizard 5 / Arcane Savant 10, then you could use a Mask of the Skull's effects at 15th level, as you described.

Comment: I particularly like that you're able to change your attuned item. Good catch

Answer (score 3):

### Magician Bard does this for Wands

The [Magician Bard archetype](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo-bard-archetypes/magician/) is able to scale the effect of wands to match his own statistics. This is accomplished with the following class feature:

> **Wand Mastery (Ex)**
>   At 10th level, when a magician uses a wand containing a spell on his spell list, he uses his Charisma bonus to set the wand’s save DC. At 16th level, when using such a wand, he uses his caster level in place of the wand’s caster level.